# Background thread in Processing

Tags: multithreading, processing

I am confused to how to create a background thread to run a certain function. I have a function readRSS() which reads an RSS off the internet but it takes a very long time to load it up, so I was wondering how to create a thread to perform this function every few hours while the visual effects of my program run. The code is shown below.

```java
int n;
float[][] points;
float lat, lon, r, t;
PVector coord;

PShape globe;
PImage earth_texture;

void setup() { 
  size(1800, 1800, P3D); 
  coord = new PVector();
  background(0); 

  n = 25;        // number of points
  r = 600;        // sphere's radius
  t = 0;          // rotation accumulator

  readRSS();
  populateGlobe();
  createGlobe();




}

void draw() { 
  background(0);
  translate(width/2, height/2); //centers earth
  rotateY(6 * radians(t += (TWO_PI / 365)));//change this to change speed of 
rotation
  shape(globe);

 //points
  fill(255,0,0);
  stroke(255,0,0);
  strokeWeight(12);

  for (int i=1; i<points.length; i++) {
    //cartesian coordinate conversion
    lat = radians(points[i][0]);
    lon = radians(points[i][1]);
    coord.x = r * cos(lat) * cos(lon);
    coord.y = r * cos(lat) * sin(lon);
    coord.z = r * sin(lat);
    point(coord.x, coord.y, coord.z);
  }
}

//creates globe and sets texture
void createGlobe(){
  //sets texture
  noStroke();
  earth_texture = loadImage("earthmap2.jpg");
  globe = createShape(SPHERE, r); 
  globe.setTexture(earth_texture);

}

void populateGlobe(){
  // populate globe w/ random GPS coordinates
  points = new float[n][2];
  for (int i=0; i<points.length; i++) {
    points[i][0] = random(-90, 90);    // latitude
    points[i][1] = random(-180, 180);  // longitude
  }
}

//this prints RSS to console
void readRSS(){

  XML rss = loadXML("https://it.einnews.com/rss/Ds5YG_pF3PymkwhH");
  XML[] news = rss.getChildren("channel/item");
  for(XML it : news){
    XML header = it.getChild("title");
    println(header.getContent());
  }

}
```

Comment: In the future, please try to narrow your problem down to a [mcve] before posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions like these are best answered by taking a look at [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/). Specifically, it sounds like you're looking for the [`thread()`](https://processing.org/reference/thread_.html) function.

```java
String time = "";

void setup() {
  size(100, 100);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  // Every 30 frames request new data
  if (frameCount % 30 == 0) {
    thread("requestData");
  }
  text(time, 10, 50);
}

// This happens as a separate thread and can take as long as it wants
void requestData() {
  JSONObject json = loadJSONObject("http://time.jsontest.com/");
  time = json.getString("time");
}
```